# How to display image from a file using XAML (not C# code behind)?

Tags: image, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to display an image, using only XAML? I have a XAML form and I need to display a logo on it. When I do this at the Initialize event, it works fine and renders the image on the screen.

Is it possible to display without using any C# code?

XAML Page:

```
<Grid>
            <Image x:Name="logo" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Source="myLogo.jpg" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        </Grid>
```

C# Code:

```
InitializeComponent();
logo.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("myLogo.jpg");
logo.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit;
```

If I comment out the lines under InitializeComponent(), the image doesn't load.
Currently, I am testing this against UWP.

Comment: XF does not have a design surface, so I'm not sure what you mean by "design time"

Comment: If you are referring to [XAML Previewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/?pivots=windows), it has been deprecated. Instead, use [XAML Hot Reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload).

Comment: @Jason Perhaps I was wrong in the usage of the word design time. I want to have the image displayed without having to write C# code. That is another way to put it.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes, that and the missing XAML designer for xamarin forms is making my life very complicated at this time.

Comment: you should be able to specify the source in the XAML.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos

Comment: In the doc Jason mentions, section [Local Images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos#local-images) describes the **rules for file naming and placement** that you must follow, to use in xaml. Note the Android naming - filename must be all lowercase `mylogo.jpg`, then usage is `Source="mylogo.jpg"`, and the ios requirement to put in appropriately named Asset Catalog Image Sets.